# Apple sign in: how to use access token to get identity token?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

From Apple docs I've read that access token is used to get identity token:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationsinglesignoncredential/3153077-accesstoken 
Does any API exist to retrieve identity token by access token? Could anyone tell something about how access token can be used?